# Suitable Document Class

Tags: documentclass

I want to prepare a documents in Latex. The documents contains, title Page, Executive summary, Two pages of introduction, Table of Content and 10 articles.  Each article contains section, subsection, mathematical equations, Figures, tables, etc. I want to insert the numbering of section as 1,2,.. within  each article ( Like in dependent article) and the numbering of section and subsection of next articles should as 1,2,... (and of subsection as 1.1..., 1.2,... etc) and so on. i want to have only the title of each article in the Table of content ( and not the section or sub section). Can you suggest me what document Class should i use. I shall be very thankful.
Best Regards
Saeed

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE...This is one of a difficult question, hence each template having a special style, so not able to mention a single name. `elsarticle` and `IEEEtran` is some of the better templates...

Comment: Start simple. And if you struggle on some specific aspect you can ask for help.

Comment: As @TeXnician says, start simple. Use e.g. the `book` or ` report` classes (or even just plain `article` for starters).